envelope solution of a family of characteristics from a first order PDE equation
There is a method called the envelope method
It is said that a family of characteristics has an envelope which is the
problem's solution.   I understand that the envelope is a curve (or surface) that is tangential to the family of curves (or surfaces) at each point.
How can this be happening?
I would like to see an example of a first-order PDE where the family of characteristics form an envelope, and this is a solution of the PDE.  Maybe I am not interpreting things correctly.

See this example.
